# Cross test: Gagliardo seminorm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

This question comes from a cross test submitted to me and my advanced calculus class (we faced very few preliminaries of the Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces).

Let $\Omega$ be bounded in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with Lipschitz boundary, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $0<s_1 <\dots <s_k<1$, $N>2s_k$ and let $u\in H^{s_k}(\Omega)=\{u\in H^{s_k}(\mathbb{R}^N): u=0 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^N\setminus\Omega\}$.
Let $$[u]_{s_k}^2=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^{2N}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+2s_k}} dx dy$$
be the usual Gagliardo seminorm.
Assume that $[u]_{s_k}^2 = 1$ and let also $0<a_1 <\dots <a_k<1$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i = 1$.
Find an upper bound for the quantity
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i [u]_{s_i}^2.$$

The alternatives were: $k$, $0$ and "none".

About me the correct answer is "none" since the correct upper bound is $1$.

In fact, as $0<s_1 <\dots <s_k<1$ and $[u]_{s_k}^2 = 1$, we have that $$[u]_{s_i}^2 \le [u]_{s_k}^2 = 1\quad \forall i\in\{1, \dots, k-1\}.$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i [u]_{s_i}^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^k a_i =1.$$
Could someone please tell me if I argued correctly?

The lecturer said that my answer was not correct.

Comment: Why is $[u]_{s_{i}}^{2} \le [u]_{s_{k}}^{2} \ \forall i < k$?

Comment: It should be true up to a constant depending on $N, s$. Did you mean this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless, I'm mistaken there is something incorrect in the question. Let $\mathcal H^s_0(\Omega) = \{ u \in H^s(\mathbb R^n) \text{ s.t. } u = 0 \text{ in } \mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega \}$ (note, it's not a good idea to call this space $H^s(\Omega)$ since this a common notation for a different space), $a:= \{a_j\}_{j=1}^k$, and define $$C_\ast(\Omega,k,a) := \sup_{u\in \mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)} \bigg \{ \sum_{j=1}^k a_j [u]_{s_j}^2 \text{ s.t. } [u]_{s_k}=1\bigg \}. $$ From what I understand, you have been asked to show that decide whether (a) $C_\ast=0$ (b) $C_\ast =k$; or (c) $C_\ast = +\infty$. None of these options appear to be correct:

---

*The answer is not (a):* Let $C_\ast =0$ and $u\in \mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)$ be such that $u \neq 0$. Then $$ 0\leqslant a_1 [u]_{s_1}^2\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^k a_j [u]_{s_j}^2 =0, $$ so $u$ is a constant in $\mathbb R^n$. Then, since $u=0$ in $\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega$, so $u=0$ which is a contradiction.

---

*The answer is not (b):* In fact, $C_\ast$ cannot be independent of $\Omega$ *and* $a$. Indeed, define $$\tilde C_\ast (k,a)= \sup_{u\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)} \bigg \{ \sum_{j=1}^k a_j [u]_{s_j}^2 \text{ s.t. } [u]_{s_k}=1\bigg \}. $$ (Note: the difference is the space of function we are taking the supremum over). I claim that $$\tag{$\ast$}\text{if }C_\ast \text{ is independent of }\Omega \text{ then }C_\ast(\Omega,k,a) = \tilde C_\ast(k,a). $$ Indeed, for a given $\Omega$ and for all $u\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n) \cap \mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)$ such that $[u]_{s_k}=1$, we have that $$ \sum_{j=1}^k a_j [u]_{s_j}^2 \leqslant \tilde C_\ast(k,a).  $$ Hence, by density of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n) \cap \mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)$ in $\mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)$, for any open bounded $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$, we have that $$C_\ast(\Omega,k,a) \leqslant \tilde C_\ast(k,a).  $$ Moreover, for all $u\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $[u]_{s_k}=1$, we have that $$ \sum_{j=1}^k a_j [u]_{s_j}^2 \leqslant C_\ast (\operatorname{supp}u,k,a ) .$$  Hence, if $C_\ast$ is independent of $\Omega$ then $\tilde C_\ast(k,a)\leqslant C_\ast (k,a )$ from which $(\ast)$ follows.

Now, let $\lambda >0$ and $u_\lambda(x):=u(\lambda x)$. We have that $$ [u_\lambda]_s = \int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\vert u(\lambda x)-u(\lambda y)\vert^2}{\vert x- y \vert^{n+2s}} \, dy \, dx =\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{\vert u(x)-u(u)\vert^2}{\lambda^{-n-2s}\vert x- y \vert^{n+2s}} \lambda^{-2n} \, dy \, dx = \lambda^{2s-n}[u]_s. $$ Next, let $b_\lambda = \{b_{\lambda,j}\}_{j=1}^k$ with $$ b_{\lambda,j}:= a_j \lambda^{n-2s_j} \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{n-2s_j} \bigg )^{-1}. $$ By construction, $\sum_{j=1}^k b_{\lambda_j}=1$. Hence, if $C_\ast$ is independent of $\Omega$ then, using $(\ast)$, we have that for all $u \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R^n)$, \begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^k a_j [u]_{s_j}^2 &= \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{n-2s} [u_\lambda]_{s_j}^2\\
&= \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{n-2s_j} \bigg ) \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^k b_j [u_\lambda]_{s_j}^2 \bigg ) \\
&\leqslant C_\ast(k,b_\lambda)  \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{n-2s_j} \bigg )[u_\lambda]_{s_k}\\
&=C_\ast(k,b_\lambda)  \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{2(s_k-s_j)} \bigg )[u]_{s_k} \\
&= C_\ast(k,b_\lambda)  \bigg ( \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{2(s_k-s_j)} \bigg ).
\end{align*} It follows that, $$C_\ast(k,a) \leqslant C_\ast(k,b_\lambda)   \sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{2(s_k-s_j)}  $$ for $\lambda>0$. However, if $C_\ast$ is also independent of $a$ then this implies that $\sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{2(s_k-s_j)} \geqslant 1 $ for all $\lambda>0$, so $$ 1\leqslant \lim_{\lambda\to 0^+}\sum_{j=1}^k a_j \lambda^{2(s_k-s_j)}=a_k<1  $$ which is a contradiction. In particular, this proves that $C_\ast$ cannot be equal to $k$.

---

*The answer is not (c):* Let $u \in \mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)$ be such that $[u]_{s_k}=1$. By Proposition 2.1 in Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces, for each $i=1,\dots,k-1$ we have that$$ [u]_{s_i} \leqslant C_i \big ( \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}^2 +[u]_{s_k}^2 \big ) = C_i \big ( \|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}^2 +1 \big )   $$ with $C_i$ a constant depending only on $n$ and $s_i$. Then, since $u\in \mathcal H^s_0(\Omega)$, using that $2<2^\star_{s_k}:=\frac{2n}{n-2s_k}$, it follows from the Hölder inequality and the fractional Sobolev inequality (Theorem 6.5 in Hitchhiker’s guide), that \begin{align*}
\| u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}&= \| u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \\
&\leqslant C(\Omega,n,s_k) \| u\|_{L^{2^\star_{s_k}}(\Omega)} \\
&=C(\Omega,n,s_k) \| u\|_{L^{2^\star_{s_k}}(\mathbb R^n)} \\
&\leqslant C(\Omega,n,s_k) [u]_{s_k} \\
&=C(\Omega,n,s_k).
\end{align*} Thus, each $[u]_{s_i}$ is bounded independently of $u$, so $C_\ast<+\infty$.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or if you find an error :)